# Germany, Thuringia, Inselsberg visible from Bavaria, Coburg?

Tags: germany, mountains

My husband and me have different opinions about this. But we both are not able to find the reasoning or proofs:

We drove from Bavaria to Thuringia via the highway A73. After passing the town Coburg, I saw a far far distanted mountain from the top of a hill (while driving) and I was sure it was the Inselsberg in Thuringia. But my husband said, this can not be possible because of the mountains around Oberhof, they would be hide the Inselsberg.

I had a look to a map and found some spots on the A73, where it could be possible to spot the Inselsberg beneath the mountains of Oberhof.

Now I search for someone, who knows this highway or the region (or who knows how to use maps better than me) and could answer my question:

**Is it possible to spot the Inselberg from a place near Coburg (maybe from the highway)?**

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid you can't see the Inselsberg from anywhere on the A73 near Coburg.
Contrary to JonathanReez's answer, the horizon is not the right choice when using heywhatsthat. Your have to choose the default map showing all parts of land that are actually visible (reddish) [image: Screenshot from heywhatsthat set to Inselsberg]
I marked those red spots east of the freeway as well as Coburg.

So you see that there are two mountaintops to the east of the A73 south of Coburg from which you can see the Inselsberg, but not from the A73 directly.

This means you saw some other mountain.

Comment: Oops. Deleted my answer.